# 2012 Nissan Juke won't start after replacing timing chain

Tags: nissan, timing-chain, juke

Replaced the timing chain and timing cover for 2012 Nissan Juke. Nothing moved so it shouldn't be out of time. Put it all back together and it cranks but won't start. Cleaning cam sensor now in case oil is the issue. Is there something else?

It did run before disassembly. The Timing chain stretched and wore a hole in the cover. Replaced both. Put it all back together and cranks but won't start. Cleaned cam sensors. Didn't help. Pulled 1 chain off and put other right on in the same place. Nothing moved so it shouldn't be out of time. Everything appears to be plugged in and getting fire.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Check for codes. Also, ensure all of your sensors are plugged back in, like the cam/crank sensors.

Comment: did it run before you disassembled it?